# Tab ( \t ) is not working correctly in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html, email, web

There is a function which send an email via default email client. In body of email message, there are few tabs between words. But, when I send this message to default email client, these tabs are not present.

JavaScript Code:

```
function SendMail() {
        try {
             var mailAddress = 'test@gmail.com';
             var mailSubject = 'Mail Subject';
         var mailBody = 'Text   goes    here';
         location.href = 'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(mailAddress) +
                '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(mailSubject) +
                '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(mailBody);
            }
            catch (err) { alert(err);} 
        }
```

Test Output: `Text goes here`
But, there should be tab instead of space between words.
Anybody, help me what's wrong with this ?

Comment: use `\t`? excess white spaces are trimmed

Comment: @Irshad: Edit your question for grammar mistakes to understand the question easily and you will get the answer very easily

Comment: This doesn't send any mail but opens a MTA like Outlook or Thunderbird, depending on clients OS settings. Not all of these mail clients do accept these additional parameters in the `mailto:` "url"

Comment: @badZoke: no excess white spaces, but tab. Actually, data supposed to be displayed tab separated. so, when it is passed via url it eliminates the tab from data.

Comment: @AxelAmthor: Yeah, you are right. I am using Outlook Express 6.0 and it eliminates the tab from contents passed in url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/VXL83/ the tabs are in the url, but with my setttings (Thunderbird, HTML email) they are eliminated from the body text by thunderbird.

```
function SendMail() {
    try {
         var mailAddress = 'test@gmail.com';
         var mailSubject = 'Mail Subject';
          var mailBody = 'Text\tgoes\there';
          var url = 'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(mailAddress) +
            '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(mailSubject) +
            '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(mailBody);
            alert(url);
            location.href = url;
        }
        catch (err) { alert(err);} 
    }

 SendMail();
```

Comment: Using Firefox+Outlook 2010 combination they get replaced by 4 spaces.

Comment: So, what should be done to avoid this elimination of tabs from url ? Remember, I am using Outlook Express 6.0 as default email client program.

Comment: you should try to send formatted text mails server side, not by generating a client side mailto: link.

Comment: In my case, I have no other option. I need to open client email program with contents and it is only possible by javascript.